# How to use a timestamp in Apache CustomLog directive

Tags: apache, logging

I would like Apache server to use a timestamp in the log file name.

I am looking to create log files every hour like this:

```
application.log.2018-01-01-15
application.log.2018-01-01-16
application.log.2018-01-01-17
application.log.2018-01-01-18
```

I have tried using CustomLog directive like this:

```
CustomLog "/var/log/apache2/healthd/application.log.%{%Y-%m-%d-%H}t" healthd
```

But it creates the file with this literal name. Does not replace the ending with a timestamp.

What is the correct way of achieving this?

Answer (score 1):

Solution is to use Apache rotatelogs.

It can be installed with `apt-get install apache2-utils` on Debian.

Apache must be configured to use it:

```
CustomLog "|/usr/bin/rotatelogs -l /var/log/apache2/healthd/application.log.%Y-%m-%d-%H 3600" logformat
```